# Is this operator bounded on $L^2(0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Define the operator $Tf(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y} f(y) \text{d}y$ for $x > 0$. Is this bounded on $L^2(0,\infty)$? or maybe on some $L^p(0,\infty)$?

We can rewrite $Tf=g*Ef$ where $Ef$ is the extension of $f$ by $0$ outside $(0,\infty)$ and $g(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. But we cannot apply Young's inequality because $g \notin L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Take the Fourier transform, which turns the convolution into a multiplication.

Comment: ok this seems to work

Comment: @HansEngler Sorry to dig this up from so long ago, but how can we take the fourier transform when $sin(x-y)/(x-y)$ is not in L1? And we don't have any such assumptions on $f$

Comment: It's in $L^2$ which is good enough.